# Python MIDI - Triggering PC_key with Piano_keys

Tags: python, keyboard, midi

I downloaded "Frederic Resurrection of Music" today, it s a game simialar to guitar hero.

Plaing piano with the pc keyboard is very hard, so I would like to create a listener with python which triggers a Pc key by the push of a midi_piano key.

Example:

```
def on_midi_key_pressed(Midi_key)
    if (Midi_key == "C1")
        push_pcKey("A")
    elif (Midi_key == "#C1")
        push_pcKey("W")
    ...
```

Is there a easy to use library that can handle this.
thanks.

Comment: This is different in every operating system.